# Positivity of $y$-value when solving differential equations when given a point

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

2 cases that I'm somewhat confused on, I think this only matters if the differential equation ends up with $y^2=...$ or $\ln|y|=...$ since you can get two solutions of different signs which you then need to solve for $y$

When $dy/dx$ only involves '$y$': ie $dy/dx = (y^2 +2y)/2$ at point $(0,-4)$. When solving for $y$, to determine if we take the positive or negative $y$-value, we sub the initial point/condition in to $dy/dx$. This will tell us if we take $+$ or $- y$, in this case we'll take the positive as $dy/dx>0$ when $y=-4$. Right?

When $dy/dx$ involves both $x$ and $y$: we need to anti-differentiate and find the constant value, after we can sub in the given point to see if the condition is satisfied. If it doesn't, we take the opposite sign of the y-value of the given point. ie $dy/dx = -x/y$ for $(1,1)$, we take $y>0$ as $1=1$.

Is what I said correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the example $y'=(y^2+2y)/2$ with $y(0)=-4$ we know that any solution around the initial point has a negative value. To change the sign the solution would have to cross $y=0$. But as $y=0$ is in itself a solution, the uniqueness theorem for differentiable ODE tells us that such a crossing is impossible.

Even more, as $y=-2$ is a constant solution of this ODE, we conclude that the IVP has a solution with $y(x)<-2$.

---

In the example $y'=-\frac xy$ with $y(1)=1$ we have that the ODE is not defined for $y=0$ so that a sign change is impossible as the solution can only be defined inside the domain of the ODE. Thus the sign at the initial point defines the sign of the whole solution.

Comment: Thanks. For the first answer, I don't quite understand how solving dy/dx = 0 gives us solutions for the differential equation? Isn't y=0,-2 just the solutions for when dy/dx=0 only?

Comment: For an autonomous ODE $y'=f(y)$, the roots of $f(y)=0$ will always give you stationary solutions.